# Running Xamarin unit tests on the target device

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, xamarin, xamarin-studio

We are creating some unit tests to test our Xamarin C# code, and would like to run those unit tests automatically (Jenkins) on an actual target device (Android or iOS) connected to the Jenkins server, not an emulator.  There are various unit test frameworks (Touch.Unit, XUnit, NUnit) to help generate a unit test application, but then I can't find a way to run those unit tests on the actual device without using Xamarin's Test Cloud (which we will use for our UI testing, but we'd rather do unit testing in-house).

Is there a command-line option to Xamarin Studio (Mac) to say "run this application on the specified device, and store the unit test output in the specified file"?

Answer (score 0):

You can run Xamarin.UITests from the command line without Xamarin Studio and without Xamarin Test Cloud using NUnit. The NUnit command line runner allows you to specify the output path for the results.

You may need to modify the Xamarin.UITests so they use the device either by hard coding that information or by passing in the data somehow with say a file or an environment variable. There is also a PreferIdeSettings method which you can call in the UITest configuration. That would allow you to hard code the device information in the UITest but when running the UITests in the IDE it would use the IDE configuration.